# A launch storyboard or xib must be provided unless the app requires full screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I don't use a storyboard/xib for launch screen and get these errors in Xcode7+.

```
- All interface orientations must be supported unless the app requires full screen.

- A launch storyboard or xib must be provided unless the app requires full screen.
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Starting from iOS9 and Xcode 7 you are required to provide a LaunchScreen.storyboard for your launch screen in order to support the new multitasking feature on iPad.

To opt out of being eligible to participate in Slide Over and Split View, add the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES.

Find out more on Apple's [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html) (check last paragraph) or watch session 205 *Getting Started with Multitasking on iPad in iOS 9* @ 10:35.

Comment: Update answer with reference to WWDC 2015 video

Comment: I've done this as well, but I'm noticing my Default-x.png images aren't being shown... Anyone else?

Comment: As explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141806/xcode-7-beta-warnings-interface-orientations-and-launch-storyboard) you can achieve the same a bit easier by enabling a checkbox under the 'General' tab of your project settings.

Answer (score 90):

Set **`Requires full screen`** to **`YES`** in your target.

[image: Requires full screen]

Comment: Additional: if you used an empty `LaunchImage` bundle as part of your `Images.xcassets` for your Launch Images Source setting the app will only display the default 3.5" screen (for iPhone 4 and older) like before the iOS 7 transition. To avoid this make sure you use at least one (placeholder) image e.g. `Default-568h@2x~iphone.png`