# Black square on Launch screen on iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9.1

I just noticed after I have upgraded to iOS 9.1 on my iPhone 6s that launch screen has a black square in the middle, so it covers the logo.
I use *LaunchScreen.xib* file. It all works on previous iOS versions and simulator.

Anyone had that experience and knows how to fix it ? Or is it OS bug that needs to be reported ?

Here is a screenshot of my launch screen.

[image]

**Edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="9059" systemVersion="14F1021" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="9049"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleAspectFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="480" height="480"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="center" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="splash_screen.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JQD-7b-VFF">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="480" height="480"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.1962193080357143" green="0.1962193080357143" blue="0.1962193080357143" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                </imageView>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.96470594409999999" green="0.96470594409999999" blue="0.96470594409999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="deviceRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="JQD-7b-VFF" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="top" id="I7G-Rj-go3"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="JQD-7b-VFF" secondAttribute="trailing" id="XkP-Lr-1sD"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="JQD-7b-VFF" secondAttribute="bottom" id="ZHX-bu-Tzq"/>
                <constraint firstItem="JQD-7b-VFF" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leading" id="oJ2-QD-G8U"/>
            </constraints>
            <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="404" y="445"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="splash_screen.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

I am quite sure the black square supposed to be image.

Comment: Can you provide content details of your xib file?

Comment: Are you looking for xml representation ? I have just simple image placed in xib file.

Comment: Have you tried only giving background color to image instead os setting image to it?

Comment: Have you try
[This: iOS 9 Splash screen is black](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627519/ios-9-splash-screen-is-black) May be you had same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was somehow related to corrupted ***.png*** image. I am surprised as it worked well everywhere else. Replaced the image and the problem is fixed.

Comment: How did you figure out that your png was corrupt. I am also chasing this bug.

Comment: For me, the .png was not corrupt, only in high resolution (probably more than the device could handle). solved it by decreasing the image quality

Comment: for me the problem was with the .png extension on the widget. Putting only the name of image  (image.png -> image) works .