# Manually Created UIWindow is Wrong Size

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiwindow, uiscreen

I am learning how to create an iOS app without Interface Builder (i.e. storyboards, xibs, etc.). Below is the basic app delegate class I am working with. The problem is that when displayed the `UIWindow` does not use up the full screen of the device (see attached screenshot). This occurs on all the devices and simulators I test with. Why isn't the fullscreen being used?

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  lazy var window: UIWindow? = {
    debugPrint("AppDelegate: Creating Window")

    let screen: UIScreen = UIScreen.mainScreen()
    let window: UIWindow = UIWindow.init(frame: screen.bounds)

    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return window
  }()

  lazy var rootViewController: ShapesViewController = {
    debugPrint("AppDelegate: Creating Root View Controller")

    let rootViewController = ShapesViewController.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    return rootViewController
  }()

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    debugPrint("AppDelegate: applicationWillEnterForeground")

    window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
}
```

[image: Why doesn't the window use the whole screen?]

Answer (score 16):

The problem turned out to be that I did not have a launch image or storyboard. For some reason without this the app defaults to the 3.5" size. Credit to this comment: [A launch storyboard or xib must be provided unless the app requires full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844803/xcode-7-error-a-launch-storyboard-or-xib-must-be-provided-unless-the-app-requi#comment-53115572)

Comment: To quote the book ["iOS 9 Programming Fundamentals with Swift"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920044345.do) by Matt Neuberg (amazing tech writer!): The presence of a `Launch screen interface file base name` key in your *Info.plist* tells the system that your app runs natively on newer device types, such as the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. Without it, your app will be displayed zoomed … you won't be getting all the pixels you're entitled to …

Answer (score 2):

This always works for me (I don't see any clear difference though). Do you mind sharing your ShapesViewController code as well?

Updated to **swift 4.2**

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Comment: The ShapesViewController is empty. I even changed the root view controller to a plain old UIViewController object and I got the same thing. I tried your sample code just to rule out any weirdness and it looks the same.

Comment: @macinjosh Maybe you should try out the sample code in a new plain project. Also did you delete the main.storyboard file?

Answer (score 0):

I know sounds silly but...
For a fresh project what macinjosh is saying works.
For a project of mine in Xcode 8 and swift 3, it didn't (probably because I deleted the launch screen and had to create again).
Just created new project fresh, and follow what macinjosh said. Then migrate all your files back in.