# SwiftUI NavigationView does not fit the screen vertically

Tags: swift

could not make NavigationView fully extend Y-direction.
Tried .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) and all options of .frame().
Preview Provider shows that everything's cool, but Simulator and a real device show the opposite. (Pics attached)

The code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Color.blue
                VStack{
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size: 36))
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really see why this works fine for you. I've got under the hood Xcode Version 11.4.1 and devices with iOS 13.4.1, let alone the bajillion of Simulators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured this out. The problem has nothing to do with NavigationView or any view at all. It turned out to be the matter of mandatory presence of a xib-file (e.g. Launch Screen) in a project. In the question I neglected to mention that I'd removed all .storyboard files.
[Here's the link for more:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844803/xcode-7-error-a-launch-storyboard-or-xib-must-be-provided-unless-the-app-requi#comment-53115572)

My question was a dud in the first place, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't see any reason why it should *not* work, but... try to change location of modifiers, like below

```
NavigationView{
    ZStack{
        Color.blue
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size: 36))
        }
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```